# compiling ffmpeg with nvidia/cuda failed loading nvcuvid

Tags: ffmpeg, cuda, nvidia

I am trying to compile an ffmpeg binary with support for using nvidia GPU's, I am running:

```
os: ubuntu 18.04
nvidia driver: nvidia-driver-390
cat /usr/local/cuda-9.0/version.txt => CUDA Version 9.0.176
gpu: 2x 1080ti
```

With the instructions shown on https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg, being:

```
git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

I first found the error `ERROR: cuda requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: ffnvcodec`, which was solved with help from https://superuser.com/questions/1299064/error-cuvid-requested-but-not-all-dependencies-are-satisfied-cuda-ffnvcodec. Below is the summary (make and make install just gave a list of commands to run):

```
git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
cd nv-codec-headers
sed 's#@@PREFIX@@#/usr/local#' ffnvcodec.pc.in > ffnvcodec.pc
sudo install -m 0755 -d '/usr/local/include/ffnvcodec'
sudo install -m 0644 include/ffnvcodec/*.h '/usr/local/include/ffnvcodec'
sudo install -m 0755 -d '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
sudo install -m 0644 ffnvcodec.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
```

With that done, I removed the ffmpeg folder, recloned it and ran within the folder:

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64
make -j 10
```

Note that the path /usr/local/cuda-9.0 **does** contain both the include and lib64 folders, and that this resulted in no errors, just deprecation warnings.

Now when running this particular ffmpeg binary, with absolute paths, using the flag `-hwaccel cuvid` results in:

```
~/Documents/ffmpeg-cuda/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -i ~/test.mp4 -vf "scale_npp=1920:1072" -vcodec h264_nvenc ~/out1.mp4 -vf scale_npp=1280:720 -vcodec h264_nvenc out2.mp4
```

Which, is exactly what they have on their website to test it, results in:

```
[h264_cuvid @ 0x556348eb94c0] Cannot load cuvidGetDecodeStatus
[h264_cuvid @ 0x556348eb94c0] Failed loading nvcuvid.
```

I have also prepended: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"` before `./configure`, but also did not make a difference.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something important I missed?

Answer (score 4):

With the ffmpeg repo https://github.com/FFmpeg/nv-codec-headers, which is *"FFmpeg version of headers required to interface with Nvidias codec APIs"*, I glanced over the fact that Linux needed a **"396.24 or newer driver"**. And only CUDA toolkit 9.2 at least, supports this driver version. So, the order of commands I used I have forgotten, but was roughly like below in order to remove nvidia drivers and cuda software;

```
sudo apt remove cuda
sudo aot-get autoremove --purge cuda
cd /var
# Here I removed files like cuda-repo-9-0-local-xxx
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
# Here I removed files like cuda-9-0-xxx.list/save
```

Now using the GUI software & Updates, in the additional drivers tab, sometimes wouldnt let me change from 390 to 396, so I'm pretty sure I first changed to Nouveau display driver, restarted the computer, and then chose 396 NVIDIA driver (open source), restarted the computer again and then now using 396, a check with `nvidia-smi` showed 396.51.
[image]

I then went to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and downloaded the 9.2 Linux Ubuntu 17.04 .deb file and then:

```
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.2/Prod2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1710-9-2-local_9.2.148-1_amd64
mv cuda-repo-ubuntu1710-9-2-local_9.2.148-1_amd64 cuda-repo-ubuntu1710-9-2-local_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite cuda-repo-ubuntu1710-9-2-local_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Now with CudaToolKit 9.2 installed with nvidia-drvier version 396.51, re-doing the steps posted in my question, resulted in no errors when running ffmpeg with `-hwaccel cuvid`. Which by the way makes a **MASSIVE** difference!

Comment: Wow, thanks for that, the error message I was having from ffmpeg was quite misleading. I'm on debian/unstable, the nvidia's 396.52 is still in experimental, `apt  install -t experimental nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-cuda-dev`, reboot, rebuild ffmpeg with cuda enabled and you should be good to go.